# Any benefits from transferring older generations Pokemon to new ones?

Tags: pokemon-seventh-generation

Are there any benefits or gifts from transferring older generations Pokemon to the newer ones?

I can't remember correctly but I read somewhere that if you traded Pokemon from Gold or Silver from Virtual Console to Ultra Sun or Ultra Moon you were able to get a full set of the johto poke balls (Apricorn).

Aside from that, is there any other benefit from transferring Pokemon from older generation (Pokemon RBY/GSC from the virtual Console, and Pokemon RSE/FRLG/DPP/HGSS/BW/B2W2/XY/ORAS) to Gen 7 games(USUM)?

By this I mean anything, like a certificate, an item, a PC Wallpaper, something obtained for taking the time to transfer your old mons.

Edit: It would be nice to also know if there is anything to be obtained from transferring Gen 3-5 to Gen 6 games, but my main interest is from Gen 7, since they are the only ones where you can get Pokemon from all generations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the seventh generation of games, there is no reward or prize for transferring your old pokémon.

ORAS did have one, however, if you transferred a pokémon from the original Ruby or Sapphire games -- [a special poster for your secret base](https://www.gamerguides.com/pokemon-oras/extra-activities/achievements/time-travel-award).

> This unique award is earned from the Game Director in Lilycove City’s Cove Lily hotel after beating the Elite Four. To earn it, you must have, as your lead Pokémon, a Pokémon that originated specifically on Pokémon Ruby or Pokémon Sapphire on the GameBoy Advance.
>
> Related games, such as Pokémon Emerald, FireRed, or LeafGreen Versions on the GBA, or Pokémon Colosseum or Pokémon XD Gale of Darkness on the GameCube will not work.
>
> When you speak with the Director, you will then be given the Time Travel Award ; a diploma which you can view initially, and then place in your Super Secret Base to view at your leisure.
>
> The Award will depict various scenes and sprites from Pokémon Ruby/Sapphire, including the Pokémon that triggered the reward using their sprite from Pokémon Ruby/Sapphire (sans Shininess if it was Shiny).

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you get the jhoto pokeballs without trading from Virtual Console G/S/C. In the GAME FREAK building in Heahea City if you talk to a guy (don't remember who) and you have a jhoto starter in your team you get the pokeballs but only once per game. For benefits i guess its all about how you see it. You can mess around with the egg you get that has the high shiny chance and get all baby pokemon shiny. Also only Virtual Crystal has the celebi event where you can shiny hunt Celebi.

Comment: In the research I did, you actually need a Pokemon from Gold or Silver to get the Apricorn set, any one goes, and you get some bonus text depending from the game the pokemon comes, there is one for Red, Blue, Yellow, Gold and Silver. But I'm not sure if this works with Crystal.

Comment: Well speaking from personal experience you don't. I have the seventh gen games and not one virtual game but still got the balls (not Apricorns).

Comment: You can get 1 set from your game from different places. You can get a max of 2 of each ball, because someone from the gamefreak building gives you a full set if you show him a mon from gold or silver.